# As3 bytearray to c# bytearray

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, byte, actionscript-2

I'm looking to convert this piece of code to c#:

```
        var local1:ByteArray= new ByteArray();
        var auth:String = root.loaderInfo.parameters.auth as String;
        var key0:String = root.loaderInfo.parameters.key0 as String;
        var key1:String = root.loaderInfo.parameters.key1 as String;
        var key2:String = root.loaderInfo.parameters.key2 as String;
        var key3:String = root.loaderInfo.parameters.key3 as String;


        local1.writeUnsignedInt(parse(auth));
        local1.writeUnsignedInt(parse(key0));
        local1.writeUnsignedInt(parse(key1));
        local1.writeUnsignedInt(parse(key2));
        local1.writeUnsignedInt(parse(key3));
        trace(local1)
```

You see how I directly print the byte array without converting it to a string. How can you do that in c#? Is suppose to print out something like this: TV˜   3   R   j  i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the array contains something that can be interpreted as character codes, then you can decode the bytes into text. For example:

```
string localText = Encoding.Default.GetString(local1);
```

The encoding to use would depend on how the text was converted to bytes in the first place.

You can use a `MemoryStream` and a `BinaryWriter` to put the integers in an array. Example:

```
string auth = "1"; // example data, would come from your object
string key0 = "2";

byte[] local1;
using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream()) {
  using (BinaryWriter w = new BinaryWriter(m)) {
    w.Write(Int32.Parse(auth));
    w.Write(Int32.Parse(key0));
  }
  local1 = m.ToArray(); 
}

foreach(var g in local1)
{
  Console.WriteLine((char)g);
}
```

Comment: Everything that goes to the byte array are numbers converted into unsigned ints. var auth:String and the others are ints

Comment: @Mark: I see. I added example code for putting integers in a byte array.

Comment: Thank you I got it to work. Had to use string g = (char)byte;

Comment: @Mark: When you have the byte array, you can use the code at the top to decode it into a string.